# odoo : How to create failed or exeption unit test scenario on odoo?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I created some unit test for odoo modules. Now i need to test exeption case which throw error message UserError for example. I see on log unit test show : 
**Ran 1 test in 0.284s

FAILED**

I want on log : 
**Ran 1 test in 5.790s

OK**

Is it possible to make it on odoo unit test ? and How to create it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use assertRaises

```
def test_case1(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SomeException): 
        do_something()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Answer (score 0):

On my case :

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:
    my_object.button_confirm()

# context.exception[0] is your error message example 'Ups wrong choice'
self.assertTrue('Ups wrong choice' == context.exception[0])
```